# The Space Debris Problem: Can a shuttle-style spaceplane even make a dent in it?

Tags: space-shuttle, debris, spaceplane

I'm a bit of a shuttle geek. Ask me what my favorite spaceplane is, I'll say the space shuttle! (Specifically, Discovery, since it launched my favorite telescope, Hubble!) While the shuttles themselves haven't been in service for at least 11 years, maybe a shuttle-style spaceplane (like maybe dreamchaser, but with add some bay doors) could help to fix, or at the very least reduce, or even make a dent in, the space junk problem. Based on facts, would it be possible to help the junk problem. It doesn't have to be manned. although that disqualifies it as a shuttle, doesn't it? It at least has to be based off of it. It would have to be able to survive at least 5 debris strikes, because we are only targeting one large piece of trash at a time. My guess is that it would require multiple to be launched at once to make a dent in the debris problem. The rocket used should have at least8,210–18,850 kg (18,100–41,560 lb), or similar to that of Atlas V.

Comment: So, launch a manned spacecraft and steer it into the path of debris...?

Comment: @GdD let me clarify. With an edit.

Comment: I see you've added "based on facts," but what facts are we supposed to use?  You've left the launch vehicle theoretical as long as it has wings and a bay door.

Comment: The X-37B space "plane", operated by the US air force is a small uncrewed shuttle.

Comment: Note that the Atlas V has a payload of 8210 kg to 18850 kg to LEO. Dream Chaser, originally designed to be launched on Atlas V, has 5000 kg of pressurized payload and 500 kg of unpressurized payload, spread between the "spaceplane" portion (little more than a reentry shell) and an expendable capsule which actually provides most of its orbital functionality. All you're doing by getting the "spaceplane" involved is using up payload you could be devoting to debris-deorbiting tugs and their propellant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would make no sense to use such a large object. Because once in the orbit with the space debris propellants would have to be supplied to reduce its own orbit (as well as that of the debris). Those propellants would be better used to remove objects from orbit rather than moving a large space truck to and from orbit.

Much better to use a much smaller rocket perhaps with an ion thruster or flimsy inflatable to create drag.